# SimpleXMLElement to array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I've got SimpleXMLElement object of data.

To convert it to array I simply

```
$data = (array) $xmlObj;
```

And its ok, but data like `<![CDATA[LOREM IPSUM]]>` it converts to empty array. I need it to be converted to normal array row.

Code:

```
    $e = simplexml_load_string($fileContent);
    $books = array();
    foreach ($e->product as $book) {
        $books[] = (array) $book;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function toArray(SimpleXMLElement $xml) {
        $array = (array)$xml;

        foreach ( array_slice($array, 0) as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value instanceof SimpleXMLElement ) {
                $array[$key] = empty($value) ? NULL : toArray($value);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
```